# Auto completion for option values on the cmdline

Tags: command-line, autocompletion

I cannot count the number of times I have tried to do this:

```
:set foldmethod=syn^I
```

It seems that completion doesn't work on option values!

In some cases options are complex strings where completion might not make sense.  (E.g. `'comments'`.)

But have there been any efforts to provide wildchar-completion for the common use-cases?

If not, how could I make the example above work?  (Assuming I wanted to complete to one of the strings `['manual', 'indent', 'expr', 'marker', 'syntax']`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
let s:option_values = {'foldmethod'  : ['manual', 'indent', 'expr', 'marker', 'syntax'],
                     \ 'bufhidden'   : ['hide', 'unload', 'delete', 'wipe'],
                     \ 'virtualedit' : ['block', 'insert', 'all', 'onemore'] ,}

set wildcharm=<c-z>

cnoremap <expr> <tab>
            \ getcmdline() !~# '^\s*set\s\+\w\+=' <bar><bar> wildmenumode() ?
            \ '<c-z>' :
            \ '<c-u>' . substitute(getcmdline(), 'set', 'Set', '') . '<c-z>'

command! -nargs=1 -complete=customlist,s:SetComplete Set exe 'set' <q-args>

function! s:SetComplete(A, L, P) abort
    let option = matchstr(a:A, '^.*\ze=')
    if !has_key(s:option_values, option)
        return
    endif
    let candidates = copy(s:option_values[option])
    call map(candidates, 'option . "=" . v:val')
    return filter(candidates, 'v:val =~ "^" . a:A')
endfunction
```

---

It first defines a dictionary `s:option_values` whose purpose is to contain your options (as its keys) and their values (as its values which are lists).  Here, as an example, 3 options + values are stored:
`'foldmethod'`, `'bufhidden'`, `'virtualedit'`.

```
set wildcharm=<c-z>
```

This line sets the `'wildcharm'` option and tells Vim that if it sees `<c-z>` in a mapping it must activate the wildmenu. Without setting this option, if you write `<tab>` in a mapping, it will simply insert a literal tab character.

```
cnoremap <expr> <tab>
```

Begin the definition of a mapping which will type the evaluation of an expression whenever you hit `<tab>` on the command-line.

```
\ getcmdline() !~# '^\s*set\s\+\w\+=' <bar><bar> wildmenumode() ?
```

The mapping tests if the command-line matches the pattern `^\s*set\s\+\w\+=`, which is a line following the form `set option=`, or if the wildmenu is active.

```
\ '<c-z>' :
```

If the previous test succeeds, the mapping activates the wildmenu.

```
\ '<c-u>' . substitute(getcmdline(), 'set', 'Set', '') . '<c-z>'
```

Otherwise, it replaces the system command `:set` with the custom command `:Set`, and activates the wildmenu.

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=customlist,s:SetComplete Set exe 'set' <q-args>
```

Define the custom command `:Set` which does the same thing as `:set`, except it can use a custom completion function whose name is here `s:SetComplete()`.

```
function! s:SetComplete(A, L, P) abort
```

Begin the definition of the custom completion function.

It must return suggestions/candidates through a list.
The `:Set` command will automatically send 3 arguments to it:

- the leading portion of the argument currently being completed on (i.e. `option=...`)
- the entire command line
- the cursor position in it

See `:h :command-completion-customlist` for more information.

```
let option = matchstr(a:A, '^.*\ze=')
```

Extract the name of the option from the argument being completed on.

```
if !has_key(s:option_values, option)
    return
endif
```

Check whether `option` is in your dictionary. If it's not, the function doesn't return anything.

```
let candidates = copy(s:option_values[option])
```

Get a copy of the list of values that the option can take from your dictionary.

```
call map(candidates, 'option . "=" . v:val')
```

For each value in the list `candidates`, prepend the string `option=` (where `option` will be evaluated).

```
return filter(candidates, 'v:val =~ "^" . a:A')
```

Remove the items from `candidates` whose beginning don't match the argument being completed on, and return the result.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, we can't add cmdline-completion to builtin commands that don't provide it. Either we "override" the command with another one that'll support completion (here, you could define `:Set` with a capital `S`), or we hack into vim source code to add what is missing.

Answer (score 2):

This was recently implemented. Just update to Vim 9.0.1958 and it will just work.

[Relevant commit](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/900894b09a95398dfc75599e9f0aa2ea25723384):

> ```
> patch 9.0.1958: cannot complete option values
> Problem:  cannot complete option values
> Solution: Add completion functions for several options
>
> Add cmdline tab-completion for setting string options
>
> Add tab-completion for setting string options on the cmdline using
> `:set=` (along with `:set+=` and `:set-=`).
>
> The existing tab completion for setting options currently only works
> when nothing is typed yet, and it only fills in with the existing value,
> e.g. when the user does `:set diffopt=<Tab>` it will be completed to
> `set diffopt=internal,filler,closeoff` and nothing else. This isn't too
> useful as a user usually wants auto-complete to suggest all the possible
> values, such as 'iblank', or 'algorithm:patience'.
>
> For set= and set+=, this adds a new optional callback function for each
> option that can be invoked when doing completion. This allows for each
> option to have control over how completion works. For example, in
> 'diffopt', it will suggest the default enumeration, but if `algorithm:`
> is selected, it will further suggest different algorithm types like
> 'meyers' and 'patience'. When using set=, the existing option value will
> be filled in as the first choice to preserve the existing behavior. When
> using set+= this won't happen as it doesn't make sense.
>
> For flag list options (e.g. 'mouse' and 'guioptions'), completion will
> take into account existing typed values (and in the case of set+=, the
> existing option value) to make sure it doesn't suggest duplicates.
>
> For set-=, there is a new `ExpandSettingSubtract` function which will
> handle flag list and comma-separated options smartly, by only suggesting
> values that currently exist in the option.
>
> Note that Vim has some existing code that adds special handling for
> 'filetype', 'syntax', and misc dir options like 'backupdir'. This change
> preserves them as they already work, instead of converting to the new
> callback API for each option.
> ```